# Merge in Snowflake- Not matched ,Update and Insert

Tags: sql, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables as below.

Source table:

| ID | EventDate | Updated_at | metre | Active_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-15 | 13 | Y |
| 1005 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-03-18 | 50 | Y |
| 1006 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-03-15 | 10 | Y |
| 1007 | 2022-03-20 | 2022-03-20 | 1 | Y |

Target table:

| ID | EventDate | Updated_at | metre | Active_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 10 | Y |
| 1002 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 | 15 | Y |
| 1003 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-01 | 20 | Y |
| 1004 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-10 | 10 | N |
| 1004 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-15 | 13 | Y |
| 1005 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-03-18 | 5 | Y |

I need to do the Update and Insert (NOT DELETE) to the Target table for the Date>='2022-03-01'. The comparison should be based on ID and Updated_at. These are the fields coming from API.

Case 1:
I need to Update Active_flag in Target Table when the record is not in Source. In this example is, ID= 1003 (as the other records don't meet the Date range filter) should be updated to Active_flage='N'. ID=1004 and Updated_as=2022-03-10 are not matching, and in Target table should have Active_flag='N'(which already has).

Case 2:
If they match ID and Updated_at, I can leave them as it is.(Like ID=1004 and updated_at=2022-03-15 Or ID=1005 and Updatyed_at=2022-03-18).

Case 3:
If they don't match and the ID is not in Target, I want the records to be INSERTED.
Like ID=1006 and ID=1007.

The desired Target table after the Merge should be:

| ID | EventDate | Updated_at | metre | Active_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 10 | Y |
| 1002 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 | 15 | Y |
| 1003 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-01 | 20 | N |
| 1004 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-10 | 10 | N |
| 1004 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-15 | 13 | Y |
| 1005 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-03-15 | 5 | Y |
| 1006 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-03-15 | 10 | Y |
| 1007 | 2022-03-20 | 2022-03-20 | 1 | Y |

My question:
I could achieve that by using Left and right joins and using two different Tasks in Snowflake, **but I just wanted to know if I can achieve that by using MERGE in Snowflake in one Task?**

I have tried this:

```
    merge into "TEST"."PUBLIC"."Target" T
using (
    SELECT b."ID",b."Updated_at",
    iff(a."ID" is null, 'NOT_MATCHED_BY_SOURCE', 'MATCHED_BY_SOURCE') SOURCE_MATCH,
    iff(b."ID" is null, 'NOT_MATCHED_BY_TARGET', 'MATCHED_BY_TARGET') TARGET_MATCH
    from  "TEST"."PUBLIC"."Source" a
    full join "TEST"."PUBLIC"."Target" b
    on a."ID" = b."ID" and a."Updated_at" = b."Updated_at") S
on S."ID" = T."ID" and S."Updated_at"= T."Updated_at"

WHEN matched  and S.SOURCE_MATCH = 'NOT_MATCHED_BY_SOURCE' and T."EventDate">='2022-03-01' then
    UPDATE SET T."Active_flag" = 'N'
WHEN not matched and S.TARGET_MATCH='NOT_MATCHED_BY_TARGET' THEN
    INSERT (T."ID",T."EventDate",T."Updated_at",T."metre",T."Active_flag") Values (a."ID",a."EventDate",a."Updated_at",a."metre",a."Active_flag")
;
```

The update part works fine as expected but I get an error on the INSERT part of the code as below:
***SQL compilation error: error line 14 at position 85 invalid identifier 'A.ID'***

Thank you in advance for your guidance and help.

Comment: while a screen shot of data is easy for you( even worse it appears to be mark down table!! why not include the mark down in the question??), it makes writing your code for you hard.. Also given you requirements seems "logical" why have to not tired to do this youself? what is the code you have from reading the doc's how does it not work for you? What shape of the data you want at the end, instead of just words, show the output.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I tried marking down the table, in the review was OK but the actual post was terrible.
I will fix the issue and follow your suggestions. I hope someone can help then.
Thanks

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim, I just applied your comments. Are you able to help, please?
Thanks

Comment: You are geting an error around “a.id” because there is no “a” alais in that scope. Use “s”, “a” is onpy valid in the scope context of thebsub-select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Setup:

```
CREATE table src_table(d int, date date, updated_at date, metre int, active_flag boolean);
CREATE table trg_table(d int, date date, updated_at date, metre int, active_flag boolean);

INSERT into src_table values 
(1004, '2022-03-10','2022-03-15', 13, true),
(1005,  '2022-03-18','2022-03-18', 50, true),
(1006,  '2022-03-15','2022-03-15', 10, true),
(1007,  '2022-03-20','2022-03-20', 1, true);

INSERT into trg_table values 
(1001,'2022-01-01','2022-01-01',10 ,true ),
(1002,'2022-01-02','2022-01-02',15 ,true ),
(1003,'2022-03-01','2022-03-01',20 ,true ),
(1004,'2022-03-10','2022-03-10',10 ,false),
(1004,'2022-03-10','2022-03-15',13 ,true ),
(1005,'2022-03-15','2022-03-15',5, true  );
```

core logic:

doing an outer join, we find the matches and non matches, which means we can workout the "stale rows" that need deactivating

```
SELECT t.d as td, s.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM trg_table where active_flag and date >= '2022-03-01') t
FULL OUTER JOIN src_table s ON t.d = s.d
order by 1;
```

the core woven into the MERGE which only rule 1 and 3 need work:

```
MERGE INTO trg_table t using (
    SELECT t.d as td, s.*
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM trg_table 
        where active_flag and date >= '2022-03-01'
    ) t
    FULL OUTER JOIN src_table s 
        ON t.d = s.d
) s on s.td = t.d 
WHEN MATCHED AND t.date >= '2022-03-01' AND s.d is null then update set active_flag = false
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT values (s.d, s.date, s.updated_at, s.metre, s.active_flag);
```

gives:

| D | DATE | UPDATED_AT | METRE | ACTIVE_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,001 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 | 10 | TRUE |
| 1,002 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 | 15 | TRUE |
| 1,003 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-01 | 20 | FALSE |
| 1,004 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-10 | 10 | FALSE |
| 1,004 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-15 | 13 | TRUE |
| 1,005 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-03-15 | 5 | TRUE |
| 1,006 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-03-15 | 10 | TRUE |
| 1,007 | 2022-03-20 | 2022-03-20 | 1 | TRUE |

Comment: Thanks @Simeon Pilgrim. I understand the concept and how you cleverly approached the problem. I am getting some errors on implementing that which I work on to see if I can fix it. Would you please let me know why I am getting that error on my own attempt that I shared?